# Last name change for Pakistan visa

Tags: visas, passports, passport-renewals, pakistan

I just received my passport 9 months ago. I also received my 2-year visa to Pakistan to travel back and forth. I changed my last name this past month.

Will I still be able to use my visa to Pakistan (even with my new last name?) or do I need to reapply for a new visa to Pakistan?

I will be changing my last name on my passport some time this month but I do not want to reapply for the visa if it's valid for 2 years.

Comment: I couldn't find an authoritative answer to this, but [this post](https://forums.immigration.com/threads/pakistani-visa-in-canceled-us-passport.233039/#post-1660365)
 suggests that you can still use your visa in a cancelled passport. However, it makes no mention of a name change. Assuming you changed your name by marriage you should carry your marriage certificate. Check with a Pakistan consulate.

Comment: Okay I can call and check, the man at the embassy is so mean but I'll try, thank you.